# Как обратиться элементу ключа в словаре?

Tags: c#, .net

### **Задача:**

У меня есть словарь, в котором хранятся всевозможные биграммы(a:b,b:c,a:b,a:c). В результативном словаре должны хранится ключ-значения

Если ключ-значение встречается один раз, либо значение общего ключа повторяется больше другого значения, то они не будут записаны

### **Пример 1:** {

В **исходном** словаре { a:b, b:c, a:b, a:c }

В **результативном** словаре будет { a:b, b:c }

В данном случае a:c не запишется, потому что ключ с данным значением имеет меньше значение повторений.

}

### **Пример 2**: {

В **исходном** словаре : { a:b, b:c, a:b, a:c }

В **результативном** словаре будет { b:c, a:c }

Итеративно ключ-значение a:c > a:b.

}

Поэтому я завел промежуточный словарь `wordCount`, который хранит ключ-значение исходного словаря как ключ, а как значение количество повторений.

Перед тем как добавить в результативный словарь, идет проверка, есть ли такой ключ в словаре `wordCount`, если нет, добавляем его в словари `wordCount`(cо значением 1 - число повторений) и в результативный словарь.

Если ключ в результативном словаре есть, но имеет другое значение, необходимо проверить число повторений данного ключ-значения, и вес ключ-значения( это про итерации ). Теперь собственно зачем мне первый элемент ключа в словаре `wordCount`, чтобы проверить больше ли оно 2.

Словарь `wordCount` выглядит так:

```
var wordCount = new Dictionary<KeyValuePair<string, string>, int>();
```

**Вопрос:** Добрать нужно до первого стринга и проверить количество повторений. Подскажите как это сделать? Спасибо!

Comment: Разделите текст логически, по абзацам. Читать, если честно, очень трудно.

Answer (score 0):

доступ можно получить так:

```
    static ((List<String> Key, List<String> Value) Keys, List<Int32> Values) GetDictionaryKeysValues(Dictionary<KeyValuePair<String, String>, Int32> dictionary)
    {
        //var keys = dictionary.Keys;
        ((List<String> Key, List<String> Value) Keys, List<Int32> Values) dic_key = ((null, null), null);

        foreach (var tt in dictionary)
        {
            dic_key.Keys.Key.Add(tt.Key.Key);
            dic_key.Keys.Value.Add(tt.Key.Value);
            dic_key.Values.Add(tt.Value);
        }
        return dic_key;
    }
```

Думаю так:

```
class Qwin : Queue<Char>
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.Aggregate("", (current, gg) => current + gg);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return ToString().GetHashCode();
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var s = obj as Queue<char>;
        var ss = ToArray();
        var zz = s?.ToArray();
        return !ss.Where((t, i) => zz != null && t != zz[i]).Any();
    }

    public static Dictionary<string, int> TrigrammSearch(string text, int characters, int numberRepetitions)
    {

        var trigramDictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        var trigramqueue = new Qwin();
        var trigramqueueTemp = new Qwin();
        var count = 0;
        var temp = "";
        foreach (var e in text)
        {
            trigramqueue.Enqueue(e);
            if (trigramqueue.Count != characters) continue;
            foreach (var a in text)
            {
                trigramqueueTemp.Enqueue(a);
                if (trigramqueueTemp.Count != characters) continue;
                var ads = trigramqueue.Equals(trigramqueueTemp);
                if (ads) count++;
                trigramqueueTemp.Dequeue();
            }
            temp = trigramqueue.Aggregate(temp, (current, gg) => current + gg);
            if (!trigramDictionary.ContainsKey(temp)) trigramDictionary.Add(temp, count);
            trigramqueue.Dequeue();
            temp = null;
            count = 0;

        }
        return trigramDictionary;
    }
```

Comment: В данной задаче у меня есть 3 условия:
1) Ключа в результативном словаре нет, и мы его добавляем в результативный словарь и wordCount

Comment: какие условия? какой исходный словарь?

Comment: Dictionary<String, String> dictionary?

Comment: var result = new Dictionary<string, string>(); - результативный словарь, в котором хранятся только те биграммы, которые соответствуют правилу, указанные в примерах выше
var tmpResult = new Dictionary<string, string>(); - временный словарь в котором хранятся всевозможные биграммы
var wordCount = new Dictionary<KeyValuePair<string, string>, int>();- словарь, в котором хранится в виде ключа, ключ-значение и кол-во его повторов

Comment: var wordInt = new Dictionary<KeyValuePair<string, string>, int>(); - данный словарь нужен для того случая, если кол-во повтором у ключ-значений одинаковое, добавляться будет то, у которого итерация больше, т.е. то, которое встречается позже

Comment: Для каждой пары (key, value) из словаря должно выполняться одно из следующих условий:
1)В тексте есть хотя бы одна биграмма (key, value), и для любой другой присутствующей в тексте биграммы (key, otherValue), начинающейся с того же слова, value должен быть лексикографически меньше otherValue.

2)Либо в тексте есть хотя бы одна триграмма (w1, w2, value), такая что w1 + " " + w2 == key и для любой другой присутствующей в тексте триграммы (w1, w2, otherValue), начинающейся с той же пары слов, value должен быть лексикографически меньше otherValue.

Comment: думаю где то так!

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85055/discussion-between-yaroslav-and-isaev-maxim).